# Is continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ necessarily differentiable?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

There are a number of continuous but nowhere-differentiable functions, none of which (to my knowledge) are bijections. *I am wondering if continuous bijection* $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ *is necessarily everywhere-differentiable.* I would think so, but am not sure how to formally approach this problem and have not found a similar question on MSE.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853639/a-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-but-invertible-function (any such continuous bijection must be * almost everywhere* differentiable)

Comment: Not exactly the same -- you ask for everywhere differentiable (which is not necessarily true (in a strong sense), see note at the bottom of p.3 here: https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/6-2.pdf)

Comment: I voted to close this question but did not delete it because I was not able to find the original question, so anyone wondering the same thing who might not find the original as well could find this one.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)$ is $x$ when $x\ge0$ and $2x$ when $x<0,$ $f$ is certainly a continuous bijection, but not differentiable at $x=0.$